# How do one decide topic for first data analysis project?

Tags: python

Suppose an absolute beginner (in the field of data analysis/data science), which is indeed my case, has decided to create a project for his/her resume.

These are the  skills he has learnt:

- Python(Pandas, NumPy, Seaborn/Matplotlib) - 2 years of experience (intermediate level)
- SQL - 1 month of experience have knowledge of basic querying
- PowerBI/Tableau - beginner level familiarity

Now, he wants to learn by practicing thus creating an end-to-end project on data analysis which contains Problem statement, Research question, hypothesis and EDA verifying or disproving his hypothesis.

But as a beginner it's very tough task. May you please guide me how do I create my first project given these parameters. (Additionally, the professional experience is 0)